# Apple maps show default region

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, apple-maps

I want to set a default region to the app, every time I open the map it should show a region. For example every time i open the map it should show "london".

I did this, but it's not centering

```
@interface AppleMapViewController ()

@end

@implementation TicinoWineAppleMapViewController
@synthesize mapView = _mapView;

#define DEFAULT_LATITUDE 46.006512
#define DEFAULT_LONGITUDE 8.952312

#define THE_SPAN 10.0f


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"ViewWillAppear");

}

- (void)createDefaultRegion
{
    MKCoordinateRegion defaultRegion;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = DEFAULT_LATITUDE;
    center.longitude = DEFAULT_LONGITUDE;

    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;
    span.longitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;

  //  defaultRegion.center = center;
  //  defaultRegion.span = span;

    defaultRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span);

    TicinoWineMapViewAnnotation *annotation = [[TicinoWineMapViewAnnotation alloc]initWithTitle:@"ciao" andCoordinate:center];
    [_mapView addAnnotation:annotation];


    [_mapView setRegion:defaultRegion animated:YES];
    [_mapView setCenterCoordinate:center animated:YES];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self createDefaultRegion];


}


@end
```

I tried both methods:

```
    [_mapView setRegion:defaultRegion animated:YES];
    [_mapView setCenterCoordinate:center animated:YES];
```

but its not centering on what I want. This could be a problem of simulator?

Comment: Have you tried it on a real device?

Comment: no, I am still using the simulator

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function. It worked for me.

- (void)recenterMap
  {

  NSArray *coordinates = [Mapsview valueForKeyPath:@"annotations.coordinate"];

  CLLocationCoordinate2D maxCoord = {-90.0f, -180.0f};
  CLLocationCoordinate2D minCoord = {90.0f, 180.0f};

  for(NSValue *value in coordinates) {

  ```
  CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {0.0f, 0.0f};

  [value getValue:&coord];

  if(coord.longitude > maxCoord.longitude) {            
      maxCoord.longitude = coord.longitude;            
  }        
  if(coord.latitude > maxCoord.latitude) {            
      maxCoord.latitude = coord.latitude;            
  }        
  if(coord.longitude < minCoord.longitude) {            
      minCoord.longitude = coord.longitude;            
  }        
  if(coord.latitude < minCoord.latitude) {            
      minCoord.latitude = coord.latitude;
  }
  ```

  }

  MKCoordinateRegion region = {{0.0f, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}};

  //region.center.longitude = (minCoord.longitude + maxCoord.longitude) / 2.0;
  // region.center.latitude = (minCoord.latitude + maxCoord.latitude) / 2.0;

  region.center.longitude = minCoord.longitude + (maxCoord.longitude - minCoord.longitude)/2.0f;
  region.center.latitude  = minCoord.latitude + (maxCoord.latitude - minCoord.latitude)/2.0f;

  region.span.longitudeDelta = (maxCoord.longitude - minCoord.longitude) * 1.5;
  region.span.latitudeDelta  = (maxCoord.latitude - minCoord.latitude) * 1.5;

  [Mapsview setRegion:region animated:YES];

}

Comment: Try it on device best results.